# Compare strings by their meaning, not contents

Tags: php, sql

I have a SQL table which contains title and author name of books and all the titles and author must be unique that means repetition is not allowed.

But I have issue, if I will enter author as `A.K. Pathak` and `A K Pathak` ...both are same, but SQL is taking them as different and if I will enter title as "`very hungry caterpillar`" and "`the very hungry caterpillar`" both are same, but SQL is taking as different.

Is there any PHP function to solve this or any js function?

Comment: No you need to add conditions for them before inserting in database.

Comment: You can differentiate between A K Pathak and A.K. Pathak as same but computer treats it as different because there are dots between A and K in one string and spaces in another string.

Comment: This is not the good way to check for the unique title and author name because, user can enter the same title and author name with a multiple combinations including spaces, special characters, upper / lower case and different length where it is difficult task to compare these string for uniqueness, the better way is check for unique book Id linke ISBN code etc.

Comment: JOIN by meaning... The future is now.

Comment: *Of course* there is no function to do this. Can you say whether "M. Cameron" and "Marc Cameron" are the same person? I can't. Can you tell whether the titles "Great Carts" and "Great Cars" really represent two different books or there's just a typo? I can't. Is "We Part 1" the first book of a series called "We" or of a series called "We Part"? Could you say? So how can there be possibly a PHP or JS function that can? With a combination of author and title you may be able to define rules for matching, but that can be hard work.

Answer (score 1):

The strings

> `A.K. Pathak` vs `A K Pathak`
>   and
>   `very hungry caterpillar` vs `the very hungry caterpillar`

are the same by it's *meaning* BUT they are different *literally* as a string, ie different letters are used.
That's why the database consider them as the same string.

**Do validate the input**
If you need to keep them unique you have to use a `validation` before the string are accepted from user input.

**Client side**
So if those strings are written down and submitted by user you can add autocomplete input that will helps with validation by suggestion of already used terms.

**Server side**
Check the value by a regex that will ignore the  most common differences such as dots, commas, spaces, a/the, etc. and compare new string with the one you have already in the database. I would suggest to keep both strings, ie original string, validated one in the same table for future comparison and reuse.

Answer (score 0):

If you can match by other field than the title, like some unique ID or ISBN code, much much better, but if you need matching by title, you could try something crazy like this:

```
SELECT * FROM books
WHERE regexp_replace(title, '[^a-zA-Z]', '', 'g') 
    ILIKE '%'|| regexp_replace('$my_search', '[^a-zA-Z]', '', 'g')||'%'
OR regexp_replace('$my_search', '[^a-zA-Z]', '', 'g') 
    ILIKE '%'|| regexp_replace(title, '[^a-zA-Z]', '', 'g')||'%'
OR regexp_replace(author, '[^a-zA-Z]', '', 'g') 
    ILIKE '%'|| regexp_replace('$my_search', '[^a-zA-Z]', '', 'g')||'%'
OR regexp_replace('$my_search', '[^a-zA-Z]', '', 'g') 
    ILIKE '%'|| regexp_replace(author, '[^a-zA-Z]', '', 'g')||'%'
```

But this solution is **NOT** 100% accurate and **ONLY** recommended as a desperate solution.